# 'Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop' warning while it's not

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

Can't get rid of this warning nevertheless doing everything right.

The error exists both in ssr and non-ssr scheme (with `NoSsr` wrapper from `material-ui`)

I'm experienced with React and know about key prop and don't have such errors in other places of project. Also React extension **shows that key props of two items are different**.

Have no ideas how to eliminate it here.

My code (simplified, the full souce 300+ lines of code is [here](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2429246))

```js
// index.tsx
export default function Index() {
    return (
        <Box display="flex">
            {items.map((item) => (
                <Item key={item.id} {...item} />
            ))}
        </Box>
    )
}
```

```js
// items.ts
export const items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'item 1',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'item 2',
    },
]
```

```js
// Item.tsx
export const Item = ({ text }) => <Box>{text}</Box>;
```

react: 18.2.0
@mui/material: 5.10.1
next: 12.2.5
styled-components: 5.3.5

Also babel-plugin-styled-components is used
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your code, but it looks like you're trying to use the key prop incorrectly. The key prop is meant to be used with lists of items, where each item in the list has a unique key. In your code, you're using the key prop on the <Item> component, but each <Item> component has the same key.

You should either remove the key prop from the <Item> component, or make sure each <Item> component has a unique key.

Hope that helps!"

Comment: @LuckyOwl pls take a look on screenshot

Comment: The error is coming from the `<UserTrackCard>` component and not your `<Item>` component. Are you sure you're editing the correct part of the code? The virtual DOM tree in your screenshot does not match the render function(s) shared in your code at all.

Comment: @Terry Sorry, I've mentioned that the code is simplified - some unimportant details are omitted so as not to overburden those who try to help me.

Here's the full source (300+ lines of code) - https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2429246

Comment: See how to share a [mcve]: I'd suggest boiling your example down into something that is digestible and minimal on Codesandbox or the likes. Your shared code contains a lot of unnecessary imports anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your error says:

> Check the render method of `UserTrackCard`.

It means that the error comes from *this* component, and not from its parent, as you seem to think. If you check the code of `<UserTrackCard>`, you can see the `key` prop is missing here:

```
<CardBody>
   {goals.map(({ isMiniGoal, text, color }) => (
      <CardBodyItem>
         {isMiniGoal && <MiniGoalBadge mr={0.5} />}
         <Typography variant="body2" color={color}>
            {text}
         </Typography>
      </CardBodyItem>
   ))}
</CardBody>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
export default function Index() {
    return (
        <Box display="flex">
            {items.map((item, index) => (
                <Item key={index} {...item} />
            ))}
        </Box>
    )
}
```

Comment: The same result

Comment: Also it's a bad practice to use array item index as a key prop.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, Tbh what you have done is right and the warning should not be there

Comment: OP is adding `key` to the wrong component.